# Как прочитать с клавиатуры длинное число?

Tags: c, длинная-арифметика

Как на чистом С реализовать использование, считывание с клавиатуры и вывод длинных чисел?
Числа настолько длинные, что `long long int` не подходит.

Сама задачка такова: пользователь вводит 2 длинных числа, а программа выводит ему их произведение на экран.

Comment: http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/longnum.php

Comment: Это хорошо, но мне бы хотелось готовое решение.
Да и в примерах там C++, а надо чистый Си.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У `gcc` есть библиотека `libquadmath`, предоставляющая тип с плавающей запятой длиной 128 бит и основные функции для работы с ним.

Answer (score 2):

[Раз](http://gmplib.org/), [два](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/bigdigits.html), [три](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/#decNumber). Все вроде написано на С.